# Laravel Lumen PHPUnit always returns 404

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I'm using Laravel Lumen 8.0. And building the Unit Tests for the endpoints. But got pretty fast stuck.

```
<?php


class ExampleTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testShouldReturnAllUsers(){
        $parameters = [
            'first_name'    => 'First_name',
            'last_name'     => 'TestUser',
            'locale'        => 'nl',
            'email'         => 'First_name@test'.rand(0,11111111111).'com',
            'password'      => 'asdasfasfgasgrresdfsgrwe'
        ];

        //$this->json('post', 'users', $parameters)
          //  ->seeStatusCode(200);

        $this->get('/users/b11d4d56-00ff-4af8-84c2-f1a14c8724c7');
        $this->seeStatusCode(200);
    }
}
```

```
There was 1 failure:

1) ExampleTest::testShouldReturnAllUsers
Expected status code 200 but received 404.
Failed asserting that 200 is identical to 404.

/Users/Sites/App/Services/users/vendor/illuminate/testing/TestResponse.php:186
/Users/Sites/App/Services/users/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Testing/Concerns/MakesHttpRequests.php:426
/Users/Sites/App/Services/users/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Testing/Concerns/MakesHttpRequests.php:437
/Users/Sites/App/Services/users/tests/ExampleTest.php:19
```

Going through endless questions here on SO. The answer has always been te same, check your APP_URL in the .env file and ensure that this is accessible and the it represents the actual URL of the application.

I check this 100 times and it is the actual URL and accessing this in the browser works.

How to move forward? Can I see where the request was pointed to?

Comment: Do your endpoints need authentication?

Comment: Let us see the controller code and the route taken from php artisan route:list, to see how the url should be and middlewares etc.